# C# - Entity to help with row creation

Tags: c#, data-structures

Given class:

```
   class SomeClass
    {
    public int intdata {get;set;}
    public string stringdata {get;set;}
    public double doubledata {get;set;}
    public string[] ToStringArray()
    {
       string one = intdata.ToString();
       string two = stringdata;
       string three = String.Format("{0:C}", doubledata);
       return new string[] {one,two,three};
    }
    }
```

Let's say we have 5 instances of `SomeClass`.  I want to take these instances and insert organize them into rows.

```
class RowHelper
{
   public void List<string[]> Rows;

   public RowHelper()
   {
      Rows = new List<string[]>();
   }
   public void CreateRows(SomeClass[] SomeClasses)
   {
       foreach(SomeClass rowData in SomeClasses)
       {
           Rows.Add(rowData.ToStringArray());
       }
   }
}
```

But, now I have no way to seperate one set of row data from the next.  I could add RowHelper Member `public int RowSize`.  Then the consumer will need to use `RowSize` to parse the rows.  Is that the best way to go about this?

For what it's worth, I am creating a helper class to turn objects into rows that can be inserted into `table tr` in the View layer of my MVC project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "separate one set of row data from the next", simply add an intermediate RowSet class between your RowHelper and your Rows.

```
class RowSet
{
    public void List<string[]> Rows = new List<string[]>();
}

class RowHelper
{
    public List<RowSet> RowSets;

    public RowHelper()
    {
        RowSets = new List<RowSet>();
    }

    public void CreateRows(SomeClass[] SomeClasses)
    {
        RowSet set = new RowSet();

        foreach(SomeClass rowData in SomeClasses)
        {
             set.Rows.Add(rowData.ToStringArray());
        }

        RowSets.Add(set);
    }
}
```

So, RowHelper has a public property which is a collection of `RowSet` instances.

`RowSet` contains your list of `Rows`.

Your `CreateRows` method can create a new instance of `RowSet`, populate it with rows and add it to the `RowSets` property.

You can now iterate over `RowHelper.RowSets` and from there, iterate over `RowSet.Rows`.

Consider how you will differentiate between your `RowSet`s and choose a collection class accordingly. For example, if you will simply access them serially, `List<RowSet>` is fine, but if you'd like to use, say, a named index, consider `Dictionary<string,RowSet>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) in `SomeClass`.

There are lots of examples on how to implement that interface. [David Hayden](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2005/03/06/implementing-icomparer-for-sorting-custom-objects/) has a blog about it.

```
class SomeClass : IComparable
{
  ...
}
```